# Flot Chart - Custom coloring of the graphic content for defining different ranges

Tags: colors, range, customization, flot

I have 2 ranges on the graph, so called ; green and red zones.
You can see it in the fiddle. 
What I am out after is to have a graph where the green range should be between 2-4 (y-axis) specifically for the 11-13 values of x axis. Basically I would like to have 2 different ranges .

Anyone knows how to do it ?

**Edit :**

To make it more clear with Michel's solution; I basically would like to add another green zone that is located in up-right of the previously located green zone (let it be in  x(13,16) and y(4,6) ).

```
 Please check the newer version ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shamaleyte/4zmgrpwz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple plugin for `Flot` to use in order to get shamaleyte his desired result.

Either create a new file and copy-paste the contents in it or download the [plugin](https://github.com/Xinjo/AreaMarkings)

Refer to it just as every other javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```

And add `areaMarkings` to the `grid` object in the options.

---

You were on the right track!

The way `Flot` draws the markings of the chart is simply to overlap everything! Layer upon layer upon layer.

---

What I've done to accomplish it is the following:

**#1:** First of I drew the `xaxis` between `x=11` and `x=13` for the `green` area. It's a giant area that spans from the `y=0` all the way to `y=12` on the `yaxis`.

**#2:** Then I filled in the entire `yaxis` between `y=0` and `y=2`, this overlapped the green area on the `yaxis` to create a `red` area spanning from `left(x=10)` to `right(x=15)`

**#3:** With the bottom `yaxis` row being red now, I then did the exact same for the top `yaxis`. Once again from `left(x=10)` to `right(x=15)` I filled in the entire `y=4` to `y=12` with a `red` area.

**#4:** I was now left with 2 white areas on the left and right side of the `green` area and between the `red` areas. All I had to do was fill those with `red` aswell. I did the same as I did with the green area, draw the `red` areas from the bottom to top. From `x=0` to `x=2` and from `x=13` to `x=15`.

```
....
markings: [{
            xaxis: {
                from: 11,
                to: 13
            },
            color: "#D7EEE1" // Green
        }, {
            yaxis: {
                from: 0,
                to: 2
            },
            color: "#F2CDEA" // Red - Bottom Row
        }, {
            yaxis: {
                from: 4,
                to: 12
            },
            color: "#F2CDEA" // Red - Top Row
        }, {
            xaxis: {
                from: 10,
                to: 11
            },
            color: "#F2CDEA" // Red - Left Column
        },{
            xaxis: {
                from: 13,
                to: 15
            },
            color: "#F2CDEA" // Red - Right Column
        }] 
....
```

---

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38bp45p4/28/) that I think comes close to your expectations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Michel,  I will try to adapt your solution to my problem; I will basically try to add another green zone into your solution, which will be located in x(13,16) and y(4,6) only.   2 green zones located in different parts of the content.

Comment: Unfortunately overlapping does not allow me to have what I want.  I always end up overwriting the first operation as soon as I try to add a green zone one level up on y axis.    Any idea how to succeed it ? I basically want to add another green zone into your solution,  which will be located in x(13,16) and y(4,6) .

Comment: Something along the lines of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38bp45p4/33/)? I couldn't find any plugins that could do what you were asking for so I made  a simple one myself.

Comment: That's the answer !  So "areaMarkings" is the way of doing such modification.  Thanks Michel .

Comment: Almost, but I'll update my answer to get to this result!

Comment: This is the sample I was out after. Adapted your solution to mine. Thanks again.  http://jsfiddle.net/shamaleyte/6gL1wzsL/

Comment: No problem! I've updated my [plugin](https://github.com/Xinjo/AreaMarkings) to allow for a better approach to your problem and it means less typing! Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gL1wzsL/3/) with the new approach.

Comment: Michel, do you think same logic could be applied for the following example ? http://jsfiddle.net/shamaleyte/mqoffv3c/1/  .  There are 3 lines in the graph. 
The ones in the top, and bottom represent the borders of red zone. The area in between should represent the green zone.

Comment: I actually kind of made it this way. If you have no other solution I will go with this one I guess.  The problem with this one is that the colored zones are not transparent.  I would like to see the square areas on the graph.

http://jsfiddle.net/shamaleyte/mqoffv3c/

Comment: I'm opening a topic in the following link ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651415/flot-chart-custom-coloring-for-defining-different-ranges-split-by-straight-lin

Comment: That's definitely possible! I've been experimenting with it for a bit and it seems to work decent. It has it's flaws as you need to specify `data series` for it to work properly. In regards for gradients, I'd have to do more research for it and see how `Flot` does that stuff internally, if I want to include it in my plugin. Here's a updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9xpd2od//)example